# How to display the decrypted file in Java without File Output?

Tags: java, encryption, netbeans

I am trying to develop a system that will decrypt a file then allows the authorized user to  view it without saving the decrypted file. This is to ensure that the other user won't be able to open the decrypted file.

The following codes produced a file output.

```
    public NewJFrame() {try{
                String key = "squirrel123";
                FileInputStream fis2 = newFileInputStream("encrypted.mui");
                FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("decrypt.rar");

                decrypt(key, fis2, fos2);
                Desktop dk=Desktop.getDesktop();
                File f = new File("decrypt.rar");
                dk.open(f);
            }
                catch (Throwable e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }}  
    public static void decrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void encryptOrDecrypt(String key, int mode, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {

    DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); // DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding for SunJCE

    if (mode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
        doCopy(cis, os);
    } else if (mode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
        doCopy(is, cos);
    }
}

public static void doCopy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
    int numBytes;
    while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
```

How can I decrypt a file without using FileOutputStream then allows the authorized user to view it after the decryption?

Comment: Can you use one of the in-memory OutputStreams, like ByteArrayOutputStream for your output stream? Sorry, I'm unable to memorize Java's strange stream trails in getting from there to a String. That would allow you to decrypt & display without necessarily touching disk.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write it to a Physical File, but just present the data instead, you may use a different writer then FileOutputStream.

For example, you can create a pair of PipedStream, decrypt and then read the result.

```
        String key = "squirrel123";
        FileInputStream fis2 = newFileInputStream("encrypted.mui");

        PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream();
        PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream(pis);

        decrypt(key, fis2, pis);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pis));
        String line;
        while( (line=reader.readLine()) != null ){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Comment: Notice, that you need to make this class final. Then it is impossible to "steal" your secret or methods like "view" with inheritance, overwriting and class folding (Groovy).

Comment: You can also use ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: @Netto i am also in the same problem but i don't know where i can put BufferedReader code. can you help me ?

Comment: @felipecrp i am also having the same problem can you help me

Comment: @KVK What do you mean by "where to put BufferedReader" ? A stream in like a pipe where you can put or read information. A Reader is an entity that handles the low level functionality of the streams, so you don't nees to worry about reading arrays of bytes and length. The point of this topic is using a diferent Output stream then the "FileOutputStream", so you don't write another file, but parse directly de data instead.